# Changing a global MySQL db file to MySQLi db file from PHP 4 to PHP 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, database-connection

I have always used the following for MySQL database connection for procedural coding not OO running on PHP 4 and now I am moving some old websites to PHP 5.4:

```
    <?php
global $db_user;
global $db_pass;
global $db_host;
global $db_name;
$db_user    = 'USERNAME';
$db_pass    = 'PASSWORD';
$db_host    = 'HOST';
$db_name    = 'DBNAME';
function do_query ( $sql ) 
{
    global $db_user;
    global $db_pass;
    global $db_host;
    global $db_name;
    mysql_pconnect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass )or die("Cant connect to $db_host: ");
    mysql_select_db( $db_name )or die("Cant select $db_name: ");
    $res = mysql_query( $sql )or die("You messed up in your sql Using <b>$sql</b>\n\r" . mysql_error());
    return $res;
}
?>
```

How can I change this to work with PHP 5.4 as all that is required for my website is to change this file as everything else now is up to date and the current way I connect with MySQLi never output errors the same way?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following:

```
<?php
$db_user    = 'USERNAME';
$db_pass    = 'PASSWORD';
$db_host    = 'HOST';
$db_name    = 'DBNAME';
function do_query ( $sql ) 
{
    mysqli_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass )or die("Cant connect to $db_host: ");
    mysqli_select_db( $db_name )or die("Cant select $db_name: ");
    $res = mysqli_query( $sql )or die("You messed up in your sql Using <b>$sql</b>\n\r" . mysqli_error());
    return $res;
}
?>
```

And use a mysqli_close(); at the end but it still doesn't work.

I also tried using it procedurally with:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

But I can't seem to make that work as a function.

I have done loads of tests with different versions but I didn't want to over fill the page with information most people already know so I just put up the original code I have used in the past as I have so many other variations I have tried. I was not just trying to pass the buck, just trying to explain what exactly I was trying to convert to MySQLi. Sorry if people think this is pointless but I am stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Since it's just three function calls, it's rather easy to edit. Where did you stumble specifically? (Also note that it's however not a smart idea to repeatedly call the database connection function for each query.)

Comment: At least inject your connection into your function if you're going to do it that way. Don't make one connection per query. And `mysqli_query` requires the connection passed as the first argument

Comment: Each time this is used, it is for one page when loading and then it shuts the connection with mysqli_close(); when done it reaches the end of the page/script. It is not constantly open.

Comment: Sidenote: If you're actually using `mysqli_close();` as shown, you need DB connection passed to it like so `mysqli_close($con);` while assigning DB connection like so `$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass,$db_name)` - `mysqli_close()` requires DB connection to be passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Sorry. I was using that for the $link example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three flaws in one post.

First, using a function to create a connection and then query is a bad idea.

Second, you're using a persistent connection. So even when the page is done the connection remains. You'll exhaust your pool of database connections like that.

Third, you're using `mysql_` functions, which are deprecated.

So here's the preferred way to do things now, using `mysqli` and an object approach. I don't recommend `$GLOBALS` normally but it sounds like you're working with legacy code

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
function do_query($sql) {
    $mysqli = $GLOBALS['mysqli'];
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql)or die("You messed up in your sql Using <b>$sql</b>\n\r" . mysqli->error);
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. The problem is that I have that function used throughout the websites as the are from over 4 years ago and I don't want to spend much time on those website as they are very basic so that is why I want to stick with the function. What are the downsides to using it as a function please?

Comment: If I use the object approach, will it still work with the scripts I have that are set out as procedural using the function?

Comment: I've changed it to use injection of the object. Regardless of which you use, `mysqli_query` (object or procedural) returns a `mysqli_result` object. You can still use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and similar functions to procedural, but they exist purely for legacy.

Comment: Thanks. So I can still use mysql_fetch_assoc(), mysql_num_rows(), etc, in a procedural format?

Comment: More or less. Just be sure it's `mysqli_`

Comment: @RA No, those 2 APIs do not mix. Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc(), mysqli_num_rows()`

Comment: @RA Plus, if any of your other code contains `mysql_` functions and you want it to run in conjunction with the `mysqli_` functions as you intend on doing, you will have to convert them all to `mysqli_`

Comment: Thank you. @Machavity for your comments and answers. Just a bit confusing for me. One last thing, with regards to the do_query($mysqli, $sql), when using it, previously I would use $query=do_query("SELECT * FROM databasename");. How would it be done now as there are 2 parts to it?

Comment: Also, thanks to @Fred -ii- and everyone else for your comments.

Comment: I see you added the $GLOBALS['mysqli'];, so does that mean can I use it the same way as before with $query=do_query("SELECT * FROM databasename"); on any page I include this file?

Comment: Yes. It's more important that you initialize outside the function than to not have a global variable

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate all your help @Machavity. Thanks to everyone else who commented.